# How can I define an application's Validation Rules in an XML file

Tags: python, xml, vb.net

I have an application that validates a CSV file against some set rules. The application checks if some "columns/fields" in the CVS are marked as mandatory, others it checks if their mandatory status is based upon another field. E.g. Column 2 has a conditional check against column 5 such that if column 5 has a value, then column 2 must also have a value.

I have already implemented this using VB and Python. Problem is this logic is hard coded in the application. What i want is to move this rules into say an XML where the application will read that XML and process the file. If the rules for processing change -and they change often- then the application remains the same and only the XML changes.

Here are two sample rules in python:

**Sample One**

```
current_column_data = 5 #data from the current position in the CSV
if validate_data_type(current_column_data, expected_data_type) == False:
    return error_message
index_to_check_against = 10 #Column against which there is a "logical" test
text_to_check = get_text(index_to_check_against)
if validate_data_type(text_to_check, expected_data_type) == False:
    return error_message
if current_column_data > 10:    #This test could be checking String Vs String so have to keep in mind that to avoid errors since current column data could be a string value
    if text_to_check <= 0:
        return "Text to check should be greater than 0 if current column data is greater than 10 "
```

**Sample Two**

```
current_column_data = "Self Employed" #data from the current position in the CSV
if validate_data_type(current_column_data, expected_data_type) == False:
    return error_message
index_to_check_against = 10 #Column against which there is a "logical" test
text_to_check = get_text(index_to_check_against)
if validate_data_type(text_to_check, expected_data_type) == False:
    return error_message
if text_to_check == "A":    #Here we expect if A is provided in the index to check, then current column should have a value hence we raise an error message
    if len(current_column_data) = 0:
        return "Current column is mandatory given that "A" is provided in Column_to_check""
```

**Note:** For each column in the CSV, we already know the data type to expect, the expected length of that field, whether its mandatory, optional or conditional and if its conditional the other column the condition is based on

Now I just need some guidance on how I can possibly do it in XML and the application reads the XML and knows what to do with each column.

Someone suggested the following sample elsewhere but I still can't wrap my head around the concept.:

```
<check left="" right="9" operation="GTE" value="3" error_message="logical failure for something" /> 
#Meaning: Column 9 should be "GTE" i.e. Greater than or equal two value 3"
```

Is there a different way to go about achieving this kind of logic or even a way to improve what I have here?

Suggestions and pointers welcome

Comment: First, the title sounds scary:  You don't want to do logic in data files.  That's rule #1.

Comment: hehe. Okay. I have changed it. Hope its less scary now.

Comment: Oh, thanks, boogeyman gone!

Answer (score 2):

This concept is called a **Domain Specific Language** (DSL) - you are effectively creating a mini-programming language for validating your CSV files. Your DSL allows you to express *succinctly* the rules for a valid CSV file.

This DSL could be expressed using XML, or an alternative approach would be to develop a library of functions in python instead. Then your DSL could be expressed as a mini-python program which is a sequence of these functions. This approach is called an in-language or "internal" DSL - and has the benefit that you have the full power of python at your disposal within your language.

Looking at your samples - you're very close to this already. When I read them, they're almost like an English description of the CSV validation rules.

Don't feel you have to go down the XML route - there's nothing wrong with keeping everything in Python

- You can split your code, so you have a python file with the "CSV validation rules" expressed in your DSL, which your need to update/redistribute frequently, and separate files which define your DSL functions, which will change less frequently
- In some cases it's even possible to develop the DSL to the point where non-programmers can update/maintain "programs" written in it

Comment: No, I don't have to go down the XML route. Its just what came to mind first. Splitting the file is what I have in mind so far but wanted the XML format so that non python programmers can update the validation engine every time it changes

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are solving is not necessarily bounded with XML.  OK, you can do validation for XML with XSD, but that means that your data needed to be XML, and I'm not sure if you can do it to extent that "if A > 3, following rule applies".

A little less elegant, but maybe simpler approach than Ross answers, is simply define set of rules as *data* and have specific function process them, which is basically what your XML example does, storing (i.e. serializing) the data using XML---but you can use any other serialization format like JSON, YAML, INI or even CSV (not that it would be advisable).

So you could concentrate on the data model of the rules.  I'll try to illustrate that with XML (but not using properties):

```
<cond name="some explanatory name">
    <if><expr>...</expr>
    <and>
        <expr>
            <left><column>9</column></left>
            <op>ge</op>
            <right>3</right>
        </expr>
        <expr>
            <left><column>1</column></left>
            <op>true</op>
            <right></right>
        </expr>
    </and>
</cond>
```

Then, you can load that to Python and traverse over it for each row, raising nice explanatory exception as appropriate.

*Edit:*  You mentioned that the file might need to be human-writable.  Note that [YAML](http://yaml.org) has been designed for that.

Similar (not the same, changed to make it better illustrate the language) structure:

```yaml
# comments, explanations...
conds:
    -   name: some explanatory name
        # seen that? no quotes needed (unless you include some of
        # quite limited set of special chars)
        if:
            expr:
                # "..."
            and:
                expr:
                    left:
                            column: 9
                    op:     ge
                    right:  3
                expr:
                    left:
                            column: 1
                    op:     true
    -   name: some other explanatory name
        # i'm using alternative notation for columns below just to have
        # them better indented (not sure about support in libs)
        if:
            expr:
                # "..."
            and:
                expr:
                    left:   { column: 9 }
                    op:     ge
                    right:  3
                expr:
                    left:   { column: 1 }
                    op:     true
```

Comment: This would be an "external-DSL" approach, and is just as valid as my answer. (I like this XML structure better than the example in the question, it's more "self documenting" and easier to understand.)